# Use kind to install different Kubernetes version

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I would like to use [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) (Kubernetes in Docker) to test a tool I am writing. I would love to have a test matrix of different Kubernetes versions to test against, is there a way to configure the kubernetes version in [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the image to be used for the nodes and choose any other published version:

```
kind create cluster --image "kindest/node:v1.14.1"
```

Available tags can be found at https://hub.docker.com/r/kindest/node/tags

Answer (score 3):

Also you can do same in kind configuration file, example:

- File: kind-config.yaml
- Content:

```yaml
# four node (two workers) cluster config
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    image: kindest/node:v1.21.14
  - role: worker
    image: kindest/node:v1.21.14
  - role: worker
    image: kindest/node:v1.21.14
  - role: worker
    image: kindest/node:v1.21.14
  - role: worker
    image: kindest/node:v1.21.14
```

> The you launch kind like this:

```
kind create cluster --config kind-config.yaml
```